# Location for 3rd Party Plug-In in Adobe Premiere Pro CS6?

Tags: macos, adobe-premiere

I'm trying to install a third party application into Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 (Mac) and I have been told the place to put it is:

```
/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Common/Plug-Ins/CS6/MediaCore/
```

however, I don't have any such pathway. I only have:

```
/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Common/MediaCache
```

or

```
/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Common/Media Cache Files
```

So, my question is, does anybody have any ideas where to put the plug-in instead?

Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It tells you where to install it ! Possibly during the install the directory will be created. I have the /Plug-ins folder under the Adobe version folder.

Answer (score 2):

there should a folder named plug-ins inside '/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Common/Plug-ins/CS6/MediaCore'

Please update us if it works or not.you should go your main hd then go to library then only you can find....

Answer (score 0):

When a path doesn't exist, you need to create it.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> and then paste the location above, it's there, just hidden.